How to make a "readonly" exception?
in Php, I would like to have my exception immutable:
readonly class MyImmutableException extends \Exception
{
}

as you can see its not possible, it causes fatal error as \Exception is not immutable.
But I would like to have all my system immutable so bad, so is exceptions

You cannot do this that way. Current behavior is part of the design and it's mentioned in "Inheritance" section of RFC for readonly classes:

Similarly how overriding of readonly properties works, a readonly class can only extend a readonly parent.

So you either keep inheriting from \Exception class or have read-only attribute applied.
But note, that it might not be even necessary to involve the core \Exception class here at all, as it should be sufficient for majority of the cases to just create own, readonly base exception class. And as long as your exception class (so base or its children, if base is abstract) implements \Throwable contract, you should be good to roll. And you can even just clone \Exception class' code to set it up.

You could do something like this and define your exception to not have any input, so there is nothing to change:
class MyImmutableException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    } 
}

You could also define some defaults if you do want that. If you dont have any setters, no-one can change it:
class MyImmutableException extends \Exception
{
    private const MESSAGE = 'I am an example';
    private const CODE = 123;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(
            self::MESSAGE,
            self::code
        );
    } 
}



I would like to have all my system immutable so bad, so is exceptions

This is a bad idea. You might have a good reason, but as a rule this is a bad rule. I suggest you research the Open/Closed principle.

a good reason is that its clean if a class is immutable. If all classes are immutable, then its a clean system. Of course, it might be an utopia and cannot be achieved fully

@JohnSmith what precisely do you mean by "clean" in this instance? Why do you think this is important or useful?

@JohnSmith I have a package in my project that has implemented your logic sortof. I cant use a few words in this comment to describe how much I hate that package. No flexibility at all. Cant extend anything, at all. Again: "Open for extension, but closed for modification". And modification doesnt talk about the value of properties, but behaviour.

hmmm so immutability can rather be an obstacle? I really want to know that package and your reasoning

@JohnSmith why don't you tell us why you think it would be useful to have universal immutability? It's a big restriction to introduce, and, as Martijn says it removes a lot of flexibility to extend things in the future if you need to, so what do you think the benefits of having that would be? What will you gain if you achieve this outcome? What problem(s) do you foresee if you don't achieve it?

@JohnSmith If you use proper public/private in your classes, you should have more than plenty control as programmer. Why would you care if someone wants to use your MyImmutableException, but with a different message which might help them more? Maybe they wanted to pass $previousException, but cant now. For no real reason other than "ye, clean!".

They now need to make a MyCustomImmutableException just to change the name. Functionaly identical, the already existing $message param would've been perfect. Instead of making things clean, things are now scattered.

And dont get me wrong, some things should be immutable. For instance an Invoice could be. Want a change? Cancel the InvoiceA and make a new one. But in my experience immutable is not applied daily at all.
